# no rotation after seting status bar hidden

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In general my app works only in portrait, but one screen should be only in landscape. So I need to rotate my view, hide status bar and add a tool bar. When the status bar is visible my view is rotating fine, but after I perform `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]`, I see no rotation.. Here is the code:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90));
    landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, +80.0, +100.0);
    [self.view setTransform:landscapeTransform];

    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    self.view.bounds  = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 320.0);

    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 480, 40)];
    [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BarBg"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 100, 30)];
    label.text = @"asdasd";
    [toolBar addSubview:label];

    [self.view addSubview:toolBar];

    self.gallery.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is working for me: the view appears rotated and i'm able to rotate it later having a default

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

I'd also add the following line at your `viewWillAppear` implementation:

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

Comment: maybe I've made some stupid mistake somewhere else ? This is driving me crazy..
Upd: Have you tried to uncomment [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]; ?

Comment: Sure i did, i also tried to do this on root and pushed controllers of the navigation stack, both worked. Are you using anything specific from the UI perspective ?

Comment: I'm using storyboards and present VC as modal, I don't think there is anything specific..

Comment: Got it. To prevent the concurrent animations conflict move the status bar logic to `viewDidLoad`, you can also use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];` to specifically declare you don't want any animation (`UIStatusBarAnimationFade` looks better for me though). Then it works, the roadblock is that the view is presented as a modal. You can also play a little with different `modalTransitionStyle` types for a modal controller.

Comment: Super ! You are a genius ! )))